# How to sort files in a folder in Mac using Terminal?

Tags: macos, sorting, terminal

If I have 3 files in a folder.The names of files are:

```
0A1c.png 
0A93.png
00A4.png
```

MacOS sort performs numerical sort in finder and after sorting the order of files is:

```
0A1c.png
00A4.png
0A93.png
```

Numerically, 0 and 00 are equal, there 00A4 comes before 0A93 in numerical sorting.

I need to perform character sorting based up ASCII value of each character such that the resulting order of files after sorting is:

```
00A4.png
0A1c.png
0A93.png
```

Typing the ls command in command prompt list all files sorted based upon character value which is the order I need in finder. What command can I use in terminal to perform character sorting of files in a folder?

Comment: CMD tag is Windows specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `sort` which is alphabetical by default:

```
ls | sort
```

Comment: this would only list the names of files in sorted order, but the order of actual files in the folder would stay same.

Comment: @DeepArora: What is the "order of actual files in the folder?"  Hint: there is no such order!  In other words what you are asking for now is completely impossible on any normal computer.  Perhaps what you should do is store the names in the order you want in a text file and read from there.

Comment: how to sort alphanumerically?

Comment: yay! found it ! `ls | sort -V`